# Finding the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1. Show with the Leibniz signature formula that $\det\biggl(\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & A_{12}\\
0 & A_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}\biggl) = \lambda \cdot \det(A_{22})$ applies whereby $\lambda \in R \land A_{22} \in R^{n,n}$.

**My idea:**
$\sigma_{1} =  \operatorname{id} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & A_{12}\\
0 & A_{22}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$ and $\sigma_{2} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & A_{22}\\
\lambda & A_{12}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

I know that if the number of transpositions are equal then I will get a positive mathematical operator otherwise I will get a negative one. But I think this approach is only useful if I have actual numbers in the matrix. I got the following out of this:

$\det A = \lambda \cdot A_{22} - 0 \cdot A_{12}$

Just to make clear what I mean here is an example where it works:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3&4\\
2&1&7\\
6&7&8
\end{pmatrix}
$ $\sigma_{1} =  \operatorname{id} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3&4\\
2&1&7\\
6&7&8
\end{pmatrix}
$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma_{2} =  
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1&7\\
1&3&4\\
6&7&8
\end{pmatrix}
$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma_{3} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3&4\\
6&7&8\\
2&1&7
\end{pmatrix}
$

$\Rightarrow$ $\sigma_{4} =  
\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 7&8\\
2&1&7\\
1&3&4
\end{pmatrix}
$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma_{5} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 7&8\\
1&3&4\\
2&1&7
\end{pmatrix}
$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma_{6} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1&7\\
6&7&8\\
1&3&4
\end{pmatrix}
$

so that $\det A = 8 -48 -49 -24 +126 +56 = 69$.

**Additional information:**
Leibniz signature formula:

$$\det: R^{n,n} \to R, A = [a_{ij}] \mapsto \det(A):= \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}sgn(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n a_{i},_{\sigma(i)}$$

How do I show now that $\det\biggl(\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & A_{12}\\
0 & A_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}\biggl) = \lambda \cdot \det(A_{22})$?

Could someone show me how to solve this proof in a proper way?

Comment: Expand your  determinant by the first column.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by that. Could you explain that a little further to me?

Comment: You say you get $\det A = \lambda\cdot A_{22}$ using the formula, so why aren't you happy with that?

Comment: Because I don't think that I actually proved the initial statement. It may sound a bit weird but I feel like that im missing something. I want to get the "proper" proof and I don't think that I have it yet.

Comment: If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix, then $A_{22}$ is just a number, so I don't know what you are concerned about. As per a 'proper' proof, you used the formula you were asked to use, and it worked. That sounds like a good proof to me :)

Comment: @Alex If you would put an answer I could select it as the best answer.

Comment: @KeJie: A determinant cant be expanded by a row or by a column, multiplying each element in the row or column by its minor, i.e. the determinant of order $n-1$ obtained  when you remove the row and the column of that element, and amking the alternate sum of all those products all those products. Didn't you see this way to compute determinants?

Comment: Ok, now I see what you actually mean by that and im familiar with that. I was just a bit confused because I didn't immediately grasp what you meant with the word expanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are right to be concerned that it's a little more tricky if $A_{22}$ is a larger matrix, since $A$ is only a $2\times 2$ matrix, $A_{22}$ is just a number and your work is correct!